# Rails has_many input from Angular2 front end won't save

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, api, angular, typescript

I'm building an Angular 2 front-end app that's getting data from a Rails 5 API. It's a kind of network inventory app.

I've got a Asset-form in Angular2 and there's an multi-select input for the ip_addresses of the asset.

I'm unable to get Rails to accept this data in the back-end.

The asset object:

`{"name":"SERVER_A","serial":"XOR-354","location_id":1,"asset_type_id":1,"model_id":3,"ip_address_ids":[5304,5305]}`

Here's my asset.service.ts:

```
createAsset(asset: Asset){

let formData = new FormData();

for(var key in asset){
  if(key == "ip_address_ids") {
    for (var i = 0; i < asset[key].length; i++) {
        formData.append("asset["+key+"][]", JSON.stringify(asset[key][i]));
        console.log("asset["+key+"][]", JSON.stringify(asset[key][i]));
    }

  }
  if(key != "id") {
    formData.append("asset["+key+"]", asset[key]);
  }
}

let headers = new Headers();

let authToken = localStorage.getItem('auth_token');
headers.append('Authorization', authToken);  

return this.http.post(this.assetUrl, formData, { headers })
                .map((response: Response) => response.json());}
```

This is what im getting in the Rails server console:

```
Started POST "/assets" for ::1 at 2017-02-06 13:58:33 +0100 


Processing by AssetsController#create as HTML   


Parameters: {"asset"=>{"name"=>"SERVER_A", "description"=>"undefined",
"serial"=>"XOR-354", "asset_tag"=>"undefined",
"firmware"=>"undefined", "ssh"=>"undefined", "telnet"=>"undefined",
"http"=>"undefined", "location_id"=>"1", "asset_type_id"=>"1",
"model_id"=>"3", "prtg_id"=>"undefined", "ticket_id"=>"undefined",
"ip_address_ids"=>"5304,5305"}}   

Unpermitted parameter: ip_address_ids
```

I've permitted the param of ip_address_ids

```
def asset_params
  params.require(:asset).permit(:name, :description, :serial, :asset_tag, :firmware, :ssh, :telnet, :http, :location_id, :asset_type_id, :model_id, :prtg_id, :ticket_id, :ip_address_ids => [])
end
```

The strange thing is that if I use the Advanced REST Client in Chrome It's successful.

[Here's an image of the REST Client](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6YA7Q.png)

The result in the Rails server console:

```
Started POST "/assets" for ::1 at 2017-02-06 14:04:42 +0100

Processing by AssetsController#create as HTML

Parameters: {"asset"=>{"name"=>"Test", "asset_type_id"=>"2", "location_id"=>"33", "model_id"=>"4", "ip_address_ids"=>["5213", "5214"]}}
```

I think that the problem is that Angular sends the IDs as a string and the REST Client sends the IDs as an Array of strings.

**Any idea on how to fix this?**

Comment: Try to set `accepts_nested_attributes` on your model (backend) and change ALL ocurrences (front and backend) of `ip_address_ids` to `ip_address_ids_atrributes`.

Comment: Isn't this only if I want to build a new IP Address? The IP's already exist in the database.

Comment: Are you sure that it already exists? As you mentioned, It isn't allowing you to pass the parameter.. `Unpermitted parameter: ip_address_ids`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `ip_address_ids` params is being passed as string, rather than array, why not use `formData = JSON.stringify({asset: asset})` instead of custom processing?

If the case is that you want to pass it as an actual `string` you should not permit it with `=> []`, only `:ip_address_ids` would be enough.

Comment: When I'm doing `formData = JSON.stringify(asset)` I'm getting this error in the Rails server console:

`Started POST "/assets" for ::1 at 2017-02-07 07:15:29 +0100
Processing by AssetsController#create as HTML
Completed 400 Bad Request in 3ms (ActiveRecord: 0.7ms)



ActionController::ParameterMissing (param is missing or the value is empty: asset):`

Comment: Try `formData = JSON.stringify({asset: asset})`

Comment: I've solved it! I'm now using just JSON and skipped FormData entirely. My POST string in asset.service.ts now looks like this: `return this.http.post(this.assetUrl, JSON.stringify({asset: asset}), { headers }).map((response: Response) => response.json());`

I've also got this in my asset-form.component.html: `ngValue]="address.id.toString()"` 

I've whitelisted the array in my asset_controller.rb in Rails:
`:ip_address_ids => []`